# Access denied after running streamlit hello

Tags: python, streamlit

I have installed streamlit via "Pip install streamlit"

Everything went well during the install. But when i try streamlit hello i get an "Acess Denied" message.

What I tried:

1. Running the prompt as Admin.
2. Creating a new environment and reinstalling streamlit there.

Nothing works. Any idea why this might be happening?

[image: The error!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me installing it in my virtual env as:

```
conda install -c conda-forge streamlit
```

instead of doing:

```
pip install streamlit
```